# LINQ querying a Dictionary against a List

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I have

```
List<string> selectedOptions;
Dictionary<string,string> masterList;
```

`masterList` comprises of Keys, which are the superset for the values in `selectedoptions`.
Now, I would like to extract all the Values for the intersecting Keys between `selectedOptions` and `masterList`.

How would the LINQ query be framed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> results = 
    dic.Join(keys, d => d.Key, x => x, (a, b) => a);
```

or of course

```
var results2 = keys.Select(k => new {key = k, value = dic[k]});
```

but this will bomb if keys don't exist.

you could fix this with a `Where(k => dic.ContainsKey(k))` clause:

```
var results3 = keys
     .Where(k => dic.ContainsKey(k))
     .Select(k => new {key = k, value = dic[k]});
```

After trawling the Linq source, I think that the last method is probably most efficient. Doing a join forces linq to make a `Lookup` (effectively a multi-entry hashtable) over one of the collections involved in the join. Seeing as we already have a Dictionary which offers the same lookup performance as a `Lookup`, building a `Lookup` is superfluous.

Comment: this does not serve my purpose. I need filtered values from the dictionary for the matching keys. This is still returning matching keys. not sure if am I doing anything wrong in interpreting the code...

Comment: @GilliVilla - results3 returns a list with both keys and values, what exactly is the problem?