# Linq Query Dictionary where value in List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` and another `List<string>`. What I am trying to achieve is a linq query to get all items out of the dictionary where any values from said dictionary are in the `List<string>`.

I found this post to be helpful, [LINQ querying a Dictionary against a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114227/linq-querying-a-dictionary-against-a-list) . And was able to write the following linq expression, however my results never actually return anything.

What I have so far.

`Data` is the dictionary and `PersonList` is the list of strings.

```
var Persons = PersonList.Where(x => Data.ContainsKey(x))
                        .Select(z => new { key = z, value = Data[z] })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Well done! But do you have any question?

Comment: Try replacing PersonList with Data. What you really need is data back from Data dictionary, not PersonList.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are you looking for *keys* or *values*?  If you're looking for *values* use

```
var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => PersonList.Contains(kvp.Value))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

If instead you really want *keys* then your code should work but another option would be:

```
var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => PersonList.Contains(kvp.Key))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, and it works flawlessly in my application. Thank you!

Comment: I tried for hours to get something like that working with the `Select()` method. All I needed was the `ToDictionary()`. Thanks mate!

Comment: This post helps me to understand how to use `.ToDictionary()` in Linq. Thanks buddy sample code where i used `ToDictionary()` method `ctx.SalesSummaries.ToDictionary(x => x.TableNumber, x => x.Status)`

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

```
var Persons = Data.Where(x=>PersonList.Contains(x.Value))
                  .Select(x=>new { key=x.Key, value=x.Value})
                  .ToList();
```

I converted the result to a list, because I noticed that you used it in your code. If you want it to a dictionary, just take a look to the answer provided by D Stanley.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to convert it ToDictionary, because your source is a dictionary:

```
var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => personList.Contains(kvp.Key))
            .Select(x => x);
```

I quickly tested it in LinqPad, but if this is a bad idea or I'm wrong, please leave a comment.

Comment: This doesn't result in a dictionary, it results in an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, T>>` - the same as an `IEnumerable<T>`, but with the extra overhead of the Key as well.