# Linq Query Dictionary where value not in List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary and another List. What I am trying to achieve is a `LINQ` query to get all items out of the dictionary where any values from said dictionary are not in the `List<string>`.
I found this post to be helpful, [Linq Query Dictionary where value in List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21704502/5227915). And was able to write the following LINQ expression.

What I have so far:
Data is the dictionary and PersonList is the list of strings.

```
var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => !PersonList.Contains(kvp.Key))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

However, my results never actually return anything.

## Update:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "John", "aaa" },
    { "Tom", "bbb" },
    { "David", "ccc" }
};

List<string> PersonList = new List<string>
{
    "Tom",
    "Peter"
};

var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => !PersonList.Contains(kvp.Key))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] (including sample data **and clear expected results**).

Comment: You want a left outer join.  See msdn examples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you made a typo here and meant to write this instead?

```
// changed to kvp.Value from kvp.Key
var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => !PersonList.Contains(kvp.Value))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This searches the values from the dictionary in the list and retains those entries which are not in the list, as per your question.

Comment: Might be worth adding a note or comment in the code where you changed something

Answer (score 2):

Answering this myself as I've been looking into the problem from wrong angle.
Following works as expected:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "John", "aaa" },
    { "Tom", "bbb" },
    { "David", "ccc" }
};

List<string> PersonList = new List<string>
{
    "Tom",
    "Peter"
};

List<string> PersonListNotInDictionary = PersonList.Where(pl => !Data.ContainsKey(pl))
                                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: `What I am trying to achieve is a linq query to get all items out of the dictionary where any values from said dictionary are not in the List.` That is the **opposite** of your answer. Your answer here is those from the list that aren't in the dictionary.

Comment: Also note that if you want to filter the `List` you have, `RemoveAll()` is a much more performant option than using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the `contains` doesn't work, because the items in the `PersonList` are other objects than the keys in your dictionary. The objects might be the same (have the same content), but if it are different object (different refences), than the `contains` will return false.

An example:

```
myObject = new myObject() { Id = 1 };

List<myObject> listOfObjects = new List<myObject>();
listOfObjects.Add(new myObject() { Id = 1 });

var result = listOfObjects.Contains(myObject); // returns false, because the item in the list is a different object than myObject

result = listOfObjects.Any(obj => obj.Id == myObject.Id); // returns true
```

I don't know what the `PersonList` consist of, but if the elements have, for instance, an `Id` property than you could do something like this:

```
var Persons = Data.Where(kvp => !PersonList.Any(person => person.Id == kvp.Key.Id))
              .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code snippet

```
var result = data.Where(d => PersonList.All(p => p != d.Value));
```